# Node.js for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop

I'm developing a bot which asks series of questions. In my code here, the first question is printed 5 times (since 5 names are in the array) before going to the next question. What I would like to do is print the first question with first name in the array then go to the next question. What should I do?

```
 var members = list.members;

  for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
      console.log('actual person - ' + members[i].name);
      yesterday = function(res, convo) {
        convo.ask("You're up " + members[i].name + '. What did you do yesterday?', function(res, convo){
          today(res, convo);
          convo.next();
        });
      }
      today = function(res, convo){
        convo.ask('What do you plan on doing today?', function(res, convo){
          block(res, convo);
          convo.next();
        });
      }
      block = function(res, convo){
        convo.ask('Is there anything standing your way?', function(res, convo) {
          convo.next();
        });
      }
      bot.startConversation(message, yesterday);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A `for` loop will not work in this case, since you have asynchronous callbacks. So you are in fact starting 5 conversations, and only then the callbacks are invoked.

It should also not be necessary to define your functions multiple times.

I don't know the API, but I would suggest to add another argument to your functions (`i`, the current member number), and chain back to the next conversation (providing `i+1` when the third function executes. Something like this:

```
var members = list.members;

function yesterday(i, res, convo) {
    if (i >= members.length) return; // end
    console.log('actual person - ' + members[i].name);
    convo.ask("You're up " + members[i].name + '. What did you do yesterday?', function(res, convo){
        today(i, res, convo);
        convo.next();
    });
}

function today(i, res, convo){
    convo.ask('What do you plan on doing today?', function(res, convo){
        block(i, res, convo);
        convo.next();
    });
}

function block(i, res, convo){
    convo.ask('Is there anything standing your way?', function(res, convo) {
        // Start next conversation...
        yesterday(i+1, res, convo);
        convo.next();
        // Or, alternatively:
        // bot.startConversation(message, yesterday.bind(null, i+1));
    });
}

bot.startConversation(message, yesterday.bind(null, 0));
```

Comment: I've tried implementing your code but there's an error. TypeError: cb is not a function.

Comment: There is no mention of `cb` in this code. You maybe did not implement it correctly?

Comment: I see. The problem was with the extra argument to `startConversation`. I altered the code, placing the `i` argument as the first, and using `bind` to make sure it gets passed.